# Where does intelliJ put kotlin.js in a Multiplatform Project

Tags: kotlin

When using IntelliJ to create a Multiplatform Project, it doesn't seem to create kotlin.js (the std lib) like it does for a js project.

Comment: Multiplatform projects always use Gradle. Creating a multiplatform project adds the kotlin-stdlib-js dependency to the JavaScript module in the project.

Answer (score 3):

As said in the docs [where the `kotlin.js` is mentioned](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/javascript/kotlin-to-javascript/kotlin-to-javascript.html#examining-the-compilation-output):

> Note: ... In a Maven or Gradle build, no library files are copied by default to the compilation output directory, see the corresponding tutorials for the instructions.

The Kotlin Multiplatform project builds are always run with Gradle, and you need to refer to the [Gradle tutorial](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/javascript/getting-started-gradle/getting-started-with-gradle.html), which says:

> By default, Gradle does not expand the JARs in the build process, so we need to add an additional step in our build to do so:
>
> ```
> task assembleWeb(type: Sync) {
>     configurations.compile.each { File file ->
>         from(zipTree(file.absolutePath), {
>             includeEmptyDirs = false
>             include { fileTreeElement ->
>                 def path = fileTreeElement.path
>                 path.endsWith(".js") && (path.startsWith("META-INF/resources/") || 
>                     !path.startsWith("META-INF/"))
>             }
>         })
>     }
>     from compileKotlin2Js.destinationDir
>     into "${projectDir}/web"
>
>     dependsOn classes
> }
>
> assemble.dependsOn assembleWeb
> ```
>
> This task copies both dependencies runtime files and the compilation output to the web directory.

Comment: Can you please convert it to build.gradle.kts?